# Google Geolocation error when debugging Ionic 2 App in Chrome with VS Code

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, geolocation, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to debug an Ionic 2 project which uses Google Geolocation API with VS Code and Cordova Tools Extension. I choose debugging option "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)" and receive following error message after hitting the run button:

message: Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400.
code: 2

As a result, the Geolocation API doesn't work. The error doesn't occur when I simply run "ionic serve" in the terminal. In that case I can't use the debugger, though.

System Information:

Mac OS 10.12.4, VS Code 1.12.1, Cordova Tools (for VS Code) 1.2.7

launch.json entry (error occurs even when "ionicLiveReload": false):

```
{
    "name": "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)",
    "type": "cordova",
    "request": "launch",
    "platform": "serve",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "devServerAddress": "localhost",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "ionicLiveReload": true,
    "devServerTimeout": 120000
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's browser are you running on? What's connection type are you using?

Comment: I'm running on Google Chrome 58.0.3029.96. It's a local connection.